# shell function that sets variables *and* returns string

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

I have a function that must set some variables from command line arguments
and return a string with the remaining command line arguments.

```
args=" -i '1' -r '2' -- '3' '4'"

parse_command_line_args () {    # $1=getopt string                             
    # set variables from options, print remaining args                          
    eval set -- $1
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case "$1" in
            --)
                shift; break ;;
            -i|-o|-r|-n)
                eval "${1#-}=\"\${2}\""
                shift ;;
            *)
                exit 1
        esac
        shift
    done
    getopt -s sh -o '' -- "$@"
}
```

Now I realise that this will never work, because if I do

```
parse_command_line_args "$args"
```

it sets the variables but the rest of the arguments are lost in the standard
output, and if I do

```
rest="$(parse_command_line_args "$args")"
```

I have the rest of the arguments but the variables are lost because it's
executed in a subshell.

So, how do I get out of this?

Comment: Put the "return value" in another variable.

Comment: @Kevin Of course... now that you've mentioned it seems pretty obvious

Comment: AT&T ksh93 has the `rest=${ parse_command_line_args "$args";}` extension (also supported by e.g. [mksh](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) and possibly others) that allows you to do that. Otherwise, see @Kevin his answer.